# radio inputs not de-selecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When selecting an alternative `radio` option, the other radio button is not being un-selected/un-checked

The JS that renders this looks like the following:

```
D.div({ className: 'stra-on-loss' },
    D.span({ className: 'bet-title' }, 'On loss:'),
    ReactRadio({ name: 'onLoss', onChange: this.updateOnLoss, defaultValue: this.state.onLossSelectedOpt  },
        D.div(
            {},
            D.input({
                type: 'radio',
                className: 'stra-on-loss-return-to-base-radio',
                value: 'return_to_base',
                disabled: this.state.active
            }),
            D.span(null, 'Return to base bet'),
            D.br()
        ),
        D.div(
            {},
            D.input({
                type: 'radio',
                className: 'stra-on-loss-increase-bet-by',
                value: 'increase_bet_by',
                disabled: this.state.active
            }),
            D.span(null, 'Increase bet by: '),
            D.input({
                type: 'text',
                ref: 'onLossQty',
                onChange: this.updateOnLossQty,
                value: this.state.onLossIncreaseQty,
                disabled: this.state.active || this.state.onLossSelectedOpt !== 'increase_bet_by'
            }),
            D.span(null, 'x')
        )
    )
)
```

The HTML DOM that's produced is as follows:

```
<div class="stra-on-loss">
    <span class="bet-title">On loss:</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="stra-on-loss-return-to-base-radio" value="return_to_base">
            <span>Return to base bet</span>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" class="stra-on-loss-increase-bet-by" value="increase_bet_by">
            <span>Increase bet by: </span>
            <input type="text" value="2" disabled="">
            <span>x</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default my `return_to_base` is selected, but once I select `increase_bet_by` they both remain selected & appears that the state value does not update either.

Here's what my `ReactRadio` class looks like:

```
define([
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'react-dom-factories',
    'create-react-class',
    'prop-types',
    'lodash'
], function(
    React,
    ReactDOM,
    ReactDOMFactory,
    CreateReactClass,
    PropTypes,
    _
){

    let D = ReactDOMFactory;

    return CreateReactClass({

        displayName: 'reactRadio',

        propTypes: {
            name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            value: PropTypes.string,
            defaultValue: PropTypes.string,
            onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
        },

        componentDidMount: function() {
            this.update();
        },

        componentDidUpdate: function() {

        },

        update: function() {
            console.log('update called');
            console.log(this.props);
            if(this.props.defaultValue && !this.props.value)
                this.setSelectedRadio(this.props.defaultValue);
        },

        change: function() {
            if(!this.props.value)
                this.props.onChange(this.getSelectedRadio());
        },

        getSelectedRadio: function() {
            const radios = this.getRadios();
            for(let i=0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
                if(radios[i].checked)
                    return radios[i].value;

            return null;
        },

        setSelectedRadio: function(value) {
            const radios = this.getRadios();
            for(let i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
                if(radios[i].value === value)
                    radios[i].checked = true;
        },

        getRadios: function() {
            return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
        },

        render: function() {
            let self = this;

            return D.div({ onChange: this.change },
                React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {

                    let newProps = { name: self.props.name };

                    console.log('render called');
                    console.log(self.props);

                    if(child.props.children)
                        React.Children.map(child.props.children, function(child) {

                            if(child.props.onChange)
                                var childrenChange = child.props.onChange;

                            _.extend(child.props, { onChange: function(e) {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    if(childrenChange)
                                        childrenChange();
                                } });
                        });

                    //If the user sends a value disable all the other options
                    if(self.props.value)
                        if(child.props.value !== self.props.value)
                            newProps.disabled = true;
                        else {
                            newProps.checked = true;
                            newProps.readOnly = true;
                        }

                    _.extend(child.props, newProps);
                    return child;
                })
            )
        }
    });

});
```

Inside the `render()` function, you can see it appears to be doing a `foreach` loop on the `this.props.children` this is how var looks inside the `console.log`: 
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the React code, but I can tell you from the resultant DOM that the reason is because the `input`s don't have a `name` attribute, which is how you define radio groups.

Comment: ^ more specific they have to share the same name

Comment: It's done using JS `querySelector` to find the `radios`